# mount.cifs can't use the same credential file that smbclient uses

Tags: linux, samba, cifs, smb

I'm trying to mount a NetApp CIFS share to one of our servers and I keep getting "Permission Denied" printed to stderr and `NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD` printed to the running `dmesg`.

```
root@xxxehpvld05 ~ $ mount.cifs -vv //zhp-nas.xxx.com/perspectives /mnt/secure/cifs -o credentials=/etc/cifs.creds
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
root@xxxehpvld05 ~ $ dmesg | tail
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
Status code returned 0xc000006a NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
Status code returned 0xc000006a NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
Status code returned 0xc000006a NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

The `smbclient` command, however works without issue, using the same exact credentials file:

```
root@xxxehpvld05 ~ $ smbclient -L //zhp-nas.xxx.com/perspectives -A /etc/cifs.creds
Domain=[XXX] OS=[Windows 5.0] Server=[Windows 2000 LAN Manager]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
        ZHPSubmit-dev   Disk
    [...snip...]
```

It seems like if one works the other should as well especially since the credentials file also specifies the domain name.

Comment: what happened to the bounty?

Comment: Never got an answer that worked for me so the bounty eventually expired and all those points went the way of the dodo.

Comment: If you can think of the answer, I'll award you a new bounty, I just don't want to keep forfeiting points if I don't get an answer.

Comment: So, I was having a similar issue (with the -13 error from kernel module). I installed `cifs-utils` package (Debian) and it resolved the issue. I spent a bit debugging this because I was not expecting _any_ support without the package having been installed, so I assumed it was. I was expecting something like "unknown filesystem" from mount, but that didn't happen.

Answer (score 7):

With out more info I can't say for sure but I have seen this issue when connecting to an older windows server that was running an older protocol version. Remember CIFS is considered a "Dialect" (type) of SMB. There are other types and older setups don't use CIFS.

Basically it's like saying two people are speaking. One Spanish and one English, and your trying to force the English speaker to understand Spanish when clearly he doesn't.

SMBclient uses a different dielect for security negotiations. (or at least detects differently).

Try

> mount -t cifs //path/thing/ /mount/point -o username=user,password=pass,**sec=ntlm**

and see what happens. (sec=ntlm is the important part)

Comment: Same issue even when specifying NTLM authentication. Same if I do `ntlm` or `ntlmv2`. I'm unsure of how to troubleshoot it so if you need more information let me know and I'll update the question. Could there be some access controls on the NetApp side that the SAN guy missed?

Comment: Version of the server software, are there any routers or switches in the way?

Comment: Same subnet. Not sure what version of Samba is on the other side since it's a NetApp ONTAP appliance.

Answer (score 4):

Playing around with the commands, I found a possible reason:

From the man page of smbclient:

```
   -A|--authentication-file=filename
       This option allows you to specify a file from which to read the
       username and password used in the connection. The format of the file is

           username = <value>
           password = <value>
           domain   = <value>

       Make certain that the permissions on the file restrict access from
       unwanted users.
```

From the man page of mount.cifs:

```
   credentials=filename
       specifies a file that contains a username and/or password and
       optionally the name of the workgroup. The format of the file is:

          username=value
          password=value
          domain=value
```

Then I created two credential files, one with spaces, as showed in the first snippet and
one without and named them `creds` and `creds.spacy`.

**The big showdown:**

With `creds` file:

```
mount.cifs -vvv //host/path /local/path -o credentials=/path/creds
```

good silence, no errors.

With `creds.spacy` file:

```
# mount.cifs -vvv //host/path /local/path -o credentials=/path/creds.spacy
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

So obviously your credentials file contains spaces, which are not understood by mount.cifs.

In addition for `smbclient` it doesn't matter if there are spaces. `creds` and `creds.spacy` did not cause any grouse.

Comment: There was an extra blank line at the end of the file but I get the same thing after deleting it. [This is](https://dpaste.de/6XLW) a slightly redacted version of what's in the creds file. Redacted and real passwords are mixed case passwords containing "!" as a special character.

Comment: There's another aspect to this, which this solution led me to find: The credentials must be in the correct order, i.e. username, password, domain and not any other order like domain, username, password (which is what I had).  This also works fine with `smbclient` but fails for `mount.cifs`.  Once I changed the order to the correct one as specified in the documentation you quoted here, it started working.  Seems like these (both mishandling of spaces and the ordering issue) are terrible bugs that should be easily fixable by whoever maintains `mount.cifs`.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility that I discovered while trying to mount a share today is that `smbmount` supports the `username=DOMAIN\\user` syntax to supply a user in a domain as the credential.

For `mount.cifs` (and `mount -t cifs`) to work, these two have to be provided separately: `-o username=user,password=pass,dom=DOMAIN`.

Comment: To mount an smb 3.0 share served by a NetApp Clustered Data ONTAP had to call out both `sec=ntlm` and `dom=DOMAIN`

Comment: this was the solution when connecting to a windows share on a domain.  
smbclient is able to use the username like user@domain while mount needs in the format shown by fiskfisk

Answer (score 2):

Adding sec=ntlm  corrected the problem for me.  I have an older NAS (netgear stora).   The default security for cifs in recent kernels is ntlmssp

Comment: Worked for me, too. I don't know the real cause yet. In case it helps someone: isilon mount on ubuntu LTS 14.04. The isilon (some SAN thingy) talks to our windows active directory. The same account worked like a charm on other machines and when directly mounting it in windows.

Comment: Extra note: 12.04 with the latest updates works fine, 14.04 is somehow part of the problem now (late april 2015).

Comment: Last extra note: the core issue was a known microsoft problem with emc isilon storage and update KB3002657 (or so my sysadmin tells me right now :-) )

Answer (score 1):

As user55518 explained, you probably have spaces in your credentials file even if you don't see them. If you edited your credentials file on Windows, you probably have `\r` at the end of your lines and that throws the error 13.

Comment: you can use the command set list in vim to check for extra tabs/spaces

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank all of u !!! for this issue, It really help me a lot!, also i found some important information about the parameter "sec=ntlm", so i leave the link if some of u are interesting about it, lines below :

[Microsoft NTLM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I was trying to mount a share directory from windows 7 desktop, but i was impossible til add the parameter "sec=ntlm" and it works, and some important detail could be that i didn't consider that my windows 7 desktop was into a domain, so I think it was the most important detail that I should consider. therefore, It works!, really thank u very much all of u!, blessings!! and good vibes! :D

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only needed to add the option `vers=3.0` (CIFS was version 1, which is no longer supported since kernel 4.13, so I switched right to SMBv3 on the server) and still I had to reboot to make it work, this is my mount line in `/etc/fstab` now:

```
auto,rw,credentials=/usr/local/etc/smb.credentials,vers=3.0,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,uid=myuser,gid=users
```

My credentials file:

```
username=myuser
password=****
domain=mydomain
```

Actually, `domain` is not needed, but it's the correct option to use according to the mount.cifs man page now.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for a while.

With following errors:

```
mount error(112): Host is down
```

here it helped to set vers=1.0 option, then it reported

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

and it turned out to be extra " characters in my credentials file

where originally I had:

```
# cat /etc/samba/cred-file
username="john"
password="secret"
```

where it should be

```
# cat /etc/samba/cred-file
username=john
password=secret
```